# jQuery and ES6 arrow functions

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In jQuery we are used to binding click handlers like this:

```
$(".all-buttons").click(function() {
    var btn = this;
    console.log(btn.innerHTML);
});
```

I would like to be able to use the same functionality with ES6 arrow functions like this:

```
$(".all-buttons").click(btn => console.log(btn.innerHTML));
```

The issue is that jQuery doesn't pass the current element as an argument like other native javascript functions do, for example `Array.forEach()`

Another issue is that arrow functions cannot be "applied" i.e. called like `fn.apply(this, args)`, which is what jQuery relies on for letting me know which element triggered the event.

I just put the "click" example here, but I would like to be able to apply this to any jQuery callback.

Does anybody have any suggestions about how to achieve this? perhaps to use a different library that does call my callbacks with the element as an argument? or perhaps a jquery plugin? or a javascript trick I don't know about?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Event handlers take an `Event` as their parameter.  That includes the element.

Comment: How would you want the `apply` to look?

Comment: Why won't you use the function keyword?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The basic functionality is trivial: The `Event` object the handler receives has a `currentTarget` property which is the same as `this`:

```
$(".all-buttons").click(e => console.log(e.currentTarget.innerHTML));
```

Note this is not the same as `e.target`:

- `target` is the element the event is targeted at, whereas
- `currentTarget` is the element the event is passing through on en route to that target on which this handler was hooked

So for instance, if you have

```
<div>
    <span>click me</span>
</div>
```

...and you have a handler hooked to that `div`, clicking the `span` will give you `e.target` = the `span`, `e.currentTarget` = the `div`.

Regarding "other libraries," library recommendations are off-topic for SO. But I'll note that on modern browsers:

- The `NodeList` returned by the DOM's own `querySelectorAll` has `forEach`, which makes it easy to loop over matches (it's also trivial to polyfill on any vaguely-recent browser)
- DOM elements also now have a `closest` method which makes event delegation with the DOM much simpler than it used to be (and again, can be polyfilled).

Comment: thanks, I figured this out not much later than posting the question, your answer is better though.

Comment: will this work $(".all-buttons").click(() => console.log(this.innerHTML)); @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @PunithJain: Only if you want the `innerHTML` of whatever `this` is where that code appears (**not** of the clicked element, since arrow functions close over `this` instead of having their own).

Comment: Logan's probably right about the dupetarget. I was thinking the other aspects of the question made it its own thing, but...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some digging around in the event argument passed by jQuery, I see that this is available:

```
$(".all-buttons").click(event => console.log(event.target.innerHTML));
```

Where event.target is the clicked button.

I don't know much about event bubbling and if the element that jQuery passes as `this` is always the same as `event.target` though.

Comment: `target` is not the correct property, it's frequently not the same as `this` in jQuery callbacks. See my answer for details.